# Can TenderCardDetailsStatus transition from 'AUTHORIZED' to 'FAILED'?

Tags: square-connect, square

The Square [Transaction Process Flow](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/overview#how-it-works-the-transactions-api-process-flow) documentation explains how a credit card [Tender](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-tender) can transition from status **AUTHORIZED** to **CAPTURED** or **VOIDED**, but the [TenderCardDetailsStatus](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-tendercarddetailsstatus) documentation also mentions a status **FAILED**.

When can the status be set to **FAILED**?  Is it possible for it to transition to **FAILED** from one of the other statuses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transaction status of **FAILED** will occur if a transaction is authorized using delay_capture and when the Capture endpoint is called it will return an error of DELAYED_TRANSACTION_FAILED.